# Pandas inplace meaning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What does the `inplace` parameter of `replace()` and `drop()` methods do?

I didn't manage to understand from the docs.

Example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')
df.replace('?',-99999, inplace=True)
df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the parameter `inplace=False`, it will create a new `DataFrame` on which the operation has been performed.

If you pass the parameter `inplace=True`, it will apply the operation directly on the `DataFrame` you're working on. Hence, the following lines are doing the same thing (conceptually):

```py
df.replace('?',-99999, inplace=True)
df = df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=False)
```

Using the `inplace` version allow you to work on a single `DataFrame`. Using the other version allows you to create a new `DataFrame` on which you can work while keeping the original one, like this:

```py
df_dropped = df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=False)
```

Comment: The main advantage of using `inplace` is lowering memory utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `inplace`, `df.replace('?',-99999, inplace=True)` creates a new dataframe which is just like `df`, but with '?' replaced by -9999. `df` is not changed. inplace changes `df`.